# jQuery .click() perform the default action before the custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code, I have two checkboxes and want to keep one disabled until the other one is enabled:

```
$(function(){
    $('#remember').live('click', function(event){
        if($('#remember').is(':checked')){
            $('#keepIn').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else
            $('#keepIn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

The problem is that this function executes before the default action and when I click in the first one `$('#remember').is(':checked')` returns false (the old value) instead of true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `change` event instead:

```
$('#remember').live('change', function(event) {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#keepIn').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#keepIn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jP3NY/

---

**NB:** `live` method is deprecated. You should better use `on` or `delegate`.

For the newer version of jQuery the solution could be as follows:

```
$('body').on('change', '#remember', function(event) {
    $('#keepIn').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

Instead of `body` you can use any parent element of `#remember`.

Comment: just 2 cents bruv please use `.on` instead of `.live` :)

Comment: Thanks, that solved it, I'll accept the answer when I can. @Tats_innit On the live vs on issue, I tried that but .on method doesn't work for me, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191966/jquery-triggerclick-not-working-with-jasmine-jquery

Comment: @Tats_innit We have no idea about what version of jQuery is used ;)

Comment: @VisioN point indeed, but I will highly recommend anyone to get the latest version `:)` else people will miss out on a lot of awesomeness :)

Comment: @Tats_innit I forgot that, I'm using 1.7.2

Comment: I am confused. What differnce a 'change' event is going to make ? And I dont see anything wrong in question too. I may be missing something very simple but can you please explain ?