# How to test a function call inside a click event with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm fairly new with Jasmine and I'm trying to test a very simple scenario

**Code under test**

```
$(function () {

    $("#add_distribution_list").click(function () {
        CommonNs.Utils.setWindowLocationHRef("hello.html");
    });

});
```

**Fixture**

```
<input type='button' value='Add' id='add_distribution_list'/>
```

**Test**

```
describe("Distribution List Page", function () {
    beforeEach(function(){
        loadFixtures('button.html');
        spyOn(CommonNs.Utils, 'setWindowLocationHRef');
    });

    it("button redirects to action2", function () {
        $('#add_distribution_list').click();
        expect( CommonNs.Utils.setWindowLocationHRef).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

**Result**

```
Expected spy setWindowLocationHRef to have been called.
```

My SpecRunner.html imports jquery, jasmine-jquery, and the utility file in which CommonNs.Utils lives.

How can I assert that the method on CommonNs.Utils has been called?

Answer (score 3):

I'd expect that you'll need to trigger click event on 'add_distribution_list' using .trigger()

```
$('#add_distribution_list').trigger('click');
```

Then use a jasmine spy to monitor the method being called.

There is a good post [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/js-ref/testing-dom-events-using-jquery-and-jasmine-2.0.html) on testing dom events with jasmine 2.x and there is a cheetsheet on using jasmine spies [here](http://tobyho.com/2011/12/15/jasmine-spy-cheatsheet/)

There is a similar question relating to .trigger on jasmine test that may also help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191966/jquery-triggerclick-not-working-with-jasmine-jquery)

Comment: I also tried 'trigger' but no difference. I do use a spy to monitor the method, don't I?

Comment: Yes I believe thats right, using spyOn(object, method) are you getting any error in your console?

Comment: I have been using that link actually! The code in the article works, but doesn't show how to assert a function has been called after a click event

Comment: just updated my answer, maybe the new link and related question will help

Comment: I understand the problem, but changing my code because the test framework can't handle such a basic requirement...thanks, but no thanks

Comment: I agree. its an odd one because I've never come accross the issue, having said that though I've used sinon for spying/mocking rather then jasmines inbuilt ones

Comment: by moving the content of the fixture directly into SpecRunner.html, makes the test to pass. Clearly, as mentioned in one of your links, it's a problem related to the fact that the fixture is inkjected in a already-loaded DOM and Jquery cannot bind. It seems such a basic requirements...